# intercept html before render event finishes but from module or do you have a better idea?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am working on a c#  asp. net web forms site with 5000 pages.

The pages are all over the place and some are using master pages and some are not.

I need to add a div to every page but I can't edit or upload every page as it is to much and to risky. The only constant is that the pages are all in the same site and all have code-behind.

I know how to intercept the html by overriding the render page event  for one page/master page but how do I do this for many but in one place.

Is it possible that there a final render event for the entire site that I could access the html  maybe calling it from a module and calling it from the web.config or maybe an  event in the Global.asax?

Is there an Application event to intercept the html with?

thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should just implement your own HttpModule :)
[Here is an example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307996).

Comment: Link is dead, please replace.